# Is there a standard algorithm to find the ideal time to poll for new data?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, polling

There is an API (COVID-19 data to be exact) which posts data every other day more or less at the same time of day (3:30pm, 3:27pm, 3:38pm: 3:58pm, 4:23pm, etc.)

I want to determine the ideal time to retrieve data with the least amount of network calls possible - so polling every 5 minutues is off limits. I want to use data from the past: So when I poll every hour and in the last X days I realized that new data will be posted between 3pm and 5pm, I do not want to poll outside of that range in the future (occasially checking for new data outside that range is okay, so I'm not ending in a too narrow range somethime in the future).
Although I want to narrow down the range where I poll for new data as much as possible.

I'm thinking of an algorithm similar to binary search where I split the time intervall between past new data timestamps with safety polls outside of that range so I end with something like a sliding window.

In addition, I think it is possible to determine a kind of gradient that specifies in which period how often new data is checked for. (i.e. checking every minute from 3:25pm-3:50pm, checkin every 5mins from 3:30pm-3:25pm and 3:50pm-4:30pm, otherwise check every hour).

I wonder if someone smarter than me already did come up with an elegant solution for that problem.

Comment: This is very broad. This problem could touch all kinds of optimization-tech there is like (random subset): Stochastic-optimization (assumptions about stochastic-process/distribution of post-times to exploit gradients) vs. Global/Derivative-free optimization (more like interval-splitting). Online-Algorithms (e.g. minimizing worst-case) or Reinforcement-learning -> exploitation (*pretty sure it's posted at time x*) vs. exploration (*but i'm investing polling-costs to reason about my guess*).Here there is not even an objective:besides *polling-costs* there is probably a *delayed information cost*

Comment: Interesting problem. I agree with the comment above that there probably isn't an perfectly ideal solution. That being said, let's figure that you only consider between 3pm and 5pm. Let's start with every 5 minutes. 2 hours / 5 minutes = 24 polls. You might just be better of taking the new data times  (from 3-5), sort and dedup (1 minute intervals). Then do some sort of backoff. IE: if the first time does work, skip X times and do the next. Repeat until you run out of times (always try the last one). X is determined by function, would could just be `X=t`, where t is the number of attempts.